# Typescript (Angular) subscribe

Tags: angular, typescript

Hi i have problem with store value in local variable. Probably is problem in sync/async function subscribe.

POST request:

```
existUser(username) {
return this.http.post(`${API_URL}/existuser`, username);
}
```

Function:

```
 onSubmit() {

    this.basicAuthenticationService.existUser(this.registerForm.value.username).subscribe(
      (data: boolean) => this.existuser = data;

    );
    //this console log is undefined(empty)
    console.log(this.existuser);
```

The console log is undefined (empty), how to save the data to local variable. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You may want to try adding async/await to your onSubmit function to get the behavior you expect. For example:

```
async onSubmit() {
  this.existUser = await this.basicAuthenticationService.existUser(this.registerForm.value.username).toPromise();

  console.log(this.existuser);
}
```

this works by converting your observable into a promise and awaiting the response from the promise before continuing.

I will add that observables are very powerful and I highly recommend understanding them fully if you intend to use Angular for large apps.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you are right it is related to asynchronous call.

There are few ways to solve this case.

The easiest one is to work with variable inside subscribe. Here you can clear storage or navigate user on another link. Like:

```
onSubmit() {

    this.basicAuthenticationService.existUser(this.registerForm.value.username).subscribe(
      (data: boolean) => {
         this.existuser = data;
         // WORK HERE WITH DATA
         // local Storage cleaning
         // navigation to login page
       });
```

2nd variant if you need to launch another http call you can do everything in stream just using pipe and switchMap/mergeMap/concatMap operator.

```
this.basicAuthenticationService.existUser(this.registerForm.value.username)
  .pipe(switchMap(data) => {
    return nextHttp.call()
})
  .subscribe(....)
```